# Get endpoint from REST request in SoapUI

Tags: rest, mocking, soapui

I'm trying to make a SOAPUI REST mock.
I have a seemingly simple question, but I just can't find an answer for it. Can you tell me how to extract an endpoint from request using groovy?

Answer (score 1):

with ReadyAPI (SOAPUI pro) I personnaly use the following script :

```
def env = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.activeEnvironment

rest = env.getRestServiceAt(0)
config = rest.getEndpoint().config
endpoint = new XmlSlurper().parseText(config.toString())

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("endpoint", endpoint.toString())
```